# Write data to influxdb from Airflow DAG using Flux query statement

Tags: python, airflow, influxdb

I'm trying to monitor custom metrics of my rpi server and send those using a DAG to `influxdb:latest` (`2.7.1` as of writing this) docker database.

I have succesfully created a default `influxdb_default` connection in Airflow and am using this task to send some example values:

```py
write_to_influxdb_task = InfluxDBOperator(
    task_id="write_to_influxdb",
    sql='{_value: 99.8, _time: now(), _field: "temp", _measurement: "celsius"} |> to(bucket:"system-stats")',
    dag=dag,
)
```

IIRC according to the [docs for write](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/write-data/influxdb/#write-data-to-influxdb) this should be the correct syntax and semantics for write operation, but when I try to run the DAG it shows me this in a log:

```
[2023-08-19, 11:46:35 CEST] {influxdb.py:56} INFO - Executing: {_value: 99.8, _time: now(), _field: "temp", _measurement: "celsius"} |> to(bucket:"system-stats")
[2023-08-19, 11:46:35 CEST] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'influxdb_default' for task execution.
[2023-08-19, 11:46:35 CEST] {influxdb.py:74} INFO - URI: http://rpi.home:8086
[2023-08-19, 11:46:35 CEST] {influxdb.py:82} INFO - URI: http://rpi.home:8086
[2023-08-19, 11:46:35 CEST] {influxdb.py:83} INFO - Organization: 79fe2ae67c512g04

... [i have skipped this part for clarity, there is a rest of a long stacktrace not as relevant to this issue]

File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/influxdb_client/_sync/rest.py", line 261, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
influxdb_client.rest.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'OSS', 'X-Influxdb-Version': 'v2.7.1', 'X-Platform-Error-Code': 'invalid', 'Date': 'Sat, 19 Aug 2023 09:51:38 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'})
HTTP response body: b'{"code":"invalid","message":"error @1:74-1:99: expected stream[A] but found {_value: float, _time: time, _measurement: string, _field: string} (record) (argument tables)"}'
[2023-08-19, 11:51:38 CEST] {taskinstance.py:1345} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

I guess the main issue is the

```
expected stream[A] but found {_value: float, _time: time, _measurement: string, _field: string} (record) (argument tables)"}'.
```

Is there any apparent fault to my Flux query that I'm not seeing? (influx newbie so idk yet)

Comment: What library provides `InfluxDBOperator`? Should the flux-formatted data really be put in the `sql` field? (influx has some support for sql-like operations and for its own 'flux' operations, depending on the version)